# Conflicting changes to the role of the relationship have been detected

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am getting this error when I try to update.

As an example similar to the structure I am working on:

I have a Blog which has an ICollection of Posts. Each Post has an ICollection of Comments. I would like to update the Blog and the Posts and the Comments all in one shot.

```
var blog = blogRepository.Load(x => x.Posts.Select(y => y.Comments)).Single(x => x.BlogID == blogVM.BlogID);

Mapper.DynamicMap(blogVM, blog);
blogRepository.Update(blogVM, blog);
blogRepository.Save();
```

When it tries to do the blogRepository.Update code, it throws an error: Conflicting changes to the role  of the relationship have been detected.

I am using AutoMapper, FluentAPI, Entity Framework 5.0 and MVC 3.0.

Any ideas?

Moneka

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error the problem was that the "children" (Post and Comments in your case) objects' reference back to its parent (Blog) needed updating. That is, Blog has state X. Blog.Posts[0].Blog has state Y.

My application was a prototype so I took the shortcut of "manually" updating the references in my model prior to updating/saving. It may not be a very pretty solution, but you could see it it at least solves your problem - and then take it from there.

I saw now that it was an old post. Maybe you already solved it? Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to resolve this issue by manually mapping the values i needed updated/added/removed. Not an elegant solution however it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I has encountered exactly the same problem with EF/ AutoMapper.

I used AutoMapper to generate object from instance of another child Class. But there was a navigation property, and auto mapped into the result. So when I tried to update, that navigation property cause the "Conflicting changes" problem. So my solution was remove the auto mapped navigation property(Actually, I remove the foreign key of the property, so EF would create new record using the property).

If both your *blog*  and *blogVM* have navigation property and, try set the blogVM into 0.